# mysql using AND for subquery - filter resultset

Tags: mysql, join, subquery

In **mysql** have a m-n relationship between **employees** and **positions** tables using a connection table **employees_positions**. I found a way to pass a position_id and retrieve the employees that have that position.

However I would also pass two [or more] position_id and retrieve the employees that have BOTH [or ALL] position_id passed.

For example looking for developers and managers would return both BOB and FRANK

DB creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `employees` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'bob'),
    (2, 'frank'),
    (3, 'jim'),
    (4, 'paul'),
    (5, 'mick');

CREATE TABLE `employees_positions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `employe_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `position_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Index 2` (`position_id`,`employe_id`)
);

INSERT INTO `employees_positions` (`id`, `employe_id`, `position_id`) VALUES
    (1, 1, 1),
    (2, 2, 1),
    (3, 3, 3),
    (4, 4, 3),
    (5, 5, 3),
    (6, 1, 2),
    (7, 1, 3),
    (8, 2, 2);

CREATE TABLE `positions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ;

INSERT INTO `positions` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
    (1, 'manager'),
    (2, 'developer'),
    (3, 'executive');
```

At the moment I am using this query to retrieve also the positions of the returned employees:

```
SELECT
  name,
  (SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(p.name)
    FROM positions AS p
      LEFT JOIN employees_positions AS e_p
        ON p.id = e_p.position_id
    WHERE e_p.employe_id = e.id) AS positionsHeld,
  (SELECT
      GROUP_CONCAT(p.id)
    FROM positions AS p
      LEFT JOIN employees_positions AS e_p
        ON p.id = e_p.position_id
    WHERE e_p.employe_id = e.id) AS positionIDs

FROM employees AS e;
```

But I would like to return only the elements that have ALL the requested **positions_id**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bohemian gave a good answer, as long as an employee was only assigned to a position once.
Another way that you could do this would be:

```
select emp.id, emp.name, 
       group_concat(p.name) as positions_held, 
       group_concat(p.id) as position_ids
  from employees emp
  join employees_positions epos on epos.employe_id = emp.id
  join positions p on p.id = epos.position_id
  join employees_positions epos1 on epos1.employe_id = emp.id and epos1.position_id = 1
  join employees_positions epos2 on epos2.employe_id = emp.id and epos2.position_id = 2
group by emp.id, emp.name;
```

As you added more positions, you would just add more lines like:

```
  join employees_positions epos1 on epos1.employe_id = emp.id and epos1.position_id = 1
```

The group_concat will give you a list of ALL the positions that the employee had, not just the ones matching the provided positions.  But the provided positions data is static and wouldn't change on a row by row basis, so you could just use your application to insert that data.

[Link to SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6959/9)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HAVING` clause to ensure they have *both* positions:

```
SELECT e.name
FROM employees e
JOIN employees_positions e_p ON e_p.employe_id = e.id
WHERE e_p.position_id in (1,2)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b6959/11)

Note that you don't need the `group_concat()` or the join to the `position` table, but if you *really* need that:

```
SELECT e.name, group_concat(p.name order by 1) postitions
FROM employees e
JOIN employees_positions e_p ON e_p.employe_id = e.id
JOIN positions p ON p.id = e_p.position_id
WHERE p.id in (1,2)
GROUP BY 1
HAVING count(*) = 2
```

See same SQLFiddle above (it has both queries).